# Custom Direct2D render batch marshaling between managed and unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, direct2d, sharpdx

I recently started playing around with the SharpDX wrapper to get high performance graphics output from a C# application. According to its creators, the performance penalty associated with using SharpDX (their own numbers indicate that going via SharpDX is about 2X slower than interfacing with DirectX from native code) is *mainly* stemming from the marshalling of draw calls from managed code to the underlying API.

Therefore I wonder if it would be a good idea to create some sort of batching of those calls in a lightweight "description language" to cut down the number of marshalleded calls per screen update to one. I'm thinking about an approach where I'm translating the calls into a byte-array-ish table that could be sent in one go to a C++ method that in turn would decode that into appropriate native D2D calls.

For example:

My (custom) layout system in C# would collect everything that is supposed to be rendered for the next screen update in a list, à la so (quasi description):

```
 1. define brush1(color(FF, 00, 00))
 2. define brush2(color(00, FF, 00))
 3. draw ellipse(brush1, origin(0, 0), radius(15, 15))
 4. draw ellipse(brush2, origin(127, 127), radius(255, 255))
 5. draw ellipse(brush2, origin(127, 0), radius(255, 255))
 6. ...
```

This list could then be encoded as a byte array (for simplicity, coordinates are given as bytes in this rough example):

```
1. 01 01 FF 00 00
2. 01 02 00 FF 00
3. 10 01 00 00 0F 0F
4. 10 02 7F 7F FF FF
5. 10 02 7F 00 FF FF
6. ...
```

Then at `Render()` this sequence is sent to a custom C++ method all at once (i.e. with just one marshalled call, rather than hundreds, maybe thousands) which parses this and does the corresponding, actual calls to the Direct2D API natively.

Is such an approach viable?

Comment: You will have performance penalty on decoding the draw instruction and their parameters in native code.

Comment: Obviously. The question is whether that penalty is smaller than the marshaling of many individual draw calls from managed code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [an application](http://www.softpedia.com/progScreenshots/Spook-ProCalc-Screenshot-207942.html), which uses Direct2D (and also Direct3D) to draw function graphs quickly. I decided on a different approach and marshalled all the drawing *along with the control's logic behind it* to the native code. That way I don't have to pass information about *what* to draw, because the native code already knows it. The only performance penalties are on passing data from managed to unmanaged code, but they are O(1)s, so I don't worry much about them.